# WindowsPhone equivalent of "UITabController with UINaviagtionController per each Tab" in iOS

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have iOS application with `UITabBarController` that contains `UINaviagtionController` for each Tab, like on the picture below.
[image: My iOS app root controller]

I also want to port my application to `WindowsPhone` (>=7.5).

My question is: Which UI components/services can I use to create the navigation flow like in my iOS app?

**Update**

1. About `UITabController` you can think like about tabs in windows [image]
2. The hierarchy of controllers that painted on the picture above mean that each tab in `UITabController` will have own `UINavigationController` (in the WP terms this is `NavigationService`). So if you will use the navigation on one tab this will not affect to navigation on other tabs.

But as far as I know by default WP application have only one instance of `NavigationService`.

So actually my question is relevant to a question: Can WP application use more than one `NavigationService`?

Comment: Can you explain for us non-iOS developers what is the result of the above design? Is it one page or a series of pages? Please update your question with the desired result also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone uses slightly different UI concepts. Instead of using `Tab` control you should use either `Panorama` or `Pivot` control. The former is used whenever you want to display completely disparate elements on a single large page, the latter is for displaying multiple views of the same data. This means that `Panorama` is used for displaying multiple views of different data.

Whenever you navigate from one page to another using `NavigationService`, it will keep the current stack. It serves as a history for the hardware Back button (unlike software button in iOS).

This means that you hold only *one* sequence of previously open pages in your application that can be navigated backwards, there cannot be any "side" stacks since they make no sense.

So if you were to navigate from one pivot item to some other application page, you would use the one and only `NavigationService`. Therefore each pivot/panorama item uses the same stack as the rest of the application.

If some things are still unclear, feel free to ask here.